# Why was "Brand New Day" selected as the opening song for "Lie to Me"?

Tags: soundtrack, lie-to-me

*Lie to Me*'s opening theme was *Brand New Day* by Ryan Star, particularly this verse:

> Dream
>   Send me a sign
>   Turn back the clock
>   Give me some time
>   I need to break out
>   And make a new name
>   Let's open our eyes
>   To the brand new day
>   It's the brand new day

Why was this selected? In what ways did the producers think that it related to the themes of the show (or why *might* they have thought that)?

Comment: Maybe because of the music? Your question seems to assume it's related to the lyrics. Similarly, "Teardrop" (by Massive Attack)'s lyrics had nothing to do with House MD, but it was still a great choice for the intro song.